# Difference of the Transmission Coefficient between Thermal and Charge Conductance by Nonequilibirum Green Function Method

Tags: greens-functions, many-body, quantum-transport, thermal-conduction

The equation 57 in the reference [Jian-Sheng Wang, Jian Wang and J. T. Lu, Quantum thermal transport in nanostructures, Eur. Phys. J. B 62, 381 (2008)] explains the the transmission coefficient for the thermal conductance, as follows:
$$T_{\omega}={Tr}\left[G^{R}\Gamma_\text{left}G^{A}\Gamma_\text{right}\right]\tag{1}$$
The equation 12 in the reference [A. R. Rocha, V. M. García-Suárez, S. Bailey, C. Lambert, J. Ferrer and S. Sanvito, Spin and molecular electronics in atomically generated orbital landscapes, Phys. Rev. B, 73, 085414 (2006)] explains the transmission coefficient for the charge conductance, as follows:
$$G=\frac{2e^{2}}{h}\mathrm{Tr}\left[\Gamma_\text{left}G_{M}^{A}\Gamma_\text{right}G_{M}^{R}\right]\tag{2}$$

It seems that these two quantities are same; except the coefficient $\frac{2e^{2}}{h}$. This means that the following thermal conductance and charge conductance also seems same.

Would anyone explain to me the difference between them; particularly, the difference in the calculation procedures for these two quantities (the transmission for the thermal and charge conductance / the thermal and charge conductance)?

Thank you in advance.